# REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: AsyncApexTests Limit exceeded

Tags: apex, unit-test

In salesforce, I am trying to run the whole suite of test class and getting the below error. How we can beat this error ? Do I need to try after sometime ? Why this error comes ?

```
{
  "Fault": {
    "faultcode": "sf:REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
    "faultstring": "REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: AsyncApexTests Limit exceeded.",
    "detail": {
      "UnexpectedErrorFault": {
        "exceptionCode": "REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
        "exceptionMessage": "AsyncApexTests Limit exceeded."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you running your tests? What parameters did you set? Have you tried deploying synchronously?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a limit to the number of tests classes you can run in 24 hour period. Clearly you have exceeded that limit. The Test Execution limit is a rolling limit, thus you have to wait few hours to start testing again.

[image: TEST Run Limit]

There are few reasons that eventually leads to test limits being exhausted.

1. Running all tests frequently to test overall coverages.
2. Multiple Devs working and testing in the Same org/sandbox
3. CI/CD implementation which is building and testing classes frequently.

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000guGZAAY

Comment: This answer would be improved by a link.

Answer (score 0):

You have exceeded your limit to execute test method in 24 hours. Limit is to The greater of **`500 or 10 multiplied by the number of test classes`** in the organization.